# Node - running a globally installed custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, v8

I'm trying to install a custom module that I've just written using npm. I'd like to be able to run it like any other command on my computer.

Its called "nawk"

package.json

```
{
  "name": "nawk",
  "preferGlobal": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "My Name <xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>",
  "description": "a simpler version of awk",
  "bin": {
    "nawk": "./index.js"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index"
  },
  "dependencies" : {
  },

  "license": "MIT",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.6"
  }
}
```

index.js

```
require('fs');

var readline = require('readline');

var args = process.argv;
args.shift();
args.shift();


var rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  terminal: false
});

rl.on('line', function (line) {
    var message = '';

    var tokens = line.split(/\s+/);

    process.argv.forEach(function(index){
        index = +index;
        var val = null;

        if(index >= 0){
            val = tokens[+index];
        } else {
            val = tokens[tokens.length + +index - 1];
        }

        if(val){
            message += val + '\t';
        }

    });
    if(message){
        console.log(message);
    }
});
```

I can install it fine, but when I go to run it I get a syntax error on the first line. This doesn't happen when I run from the directory.

I install it like this

```
> sudo npm install -g $(pwd)
```

then I try and run it like this.

```
> echo hi how are you | nawk 0 -1
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/nawk: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `'fs''
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/nawk: line 1: `require('fs');'
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I needed to add this to the top of the index file

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');

...
```

Comment: I never had this issue (I wrote only one module npm), mais due to the file encodage.